# Create a ticker which reloads the text file offscreen

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a ticker which reloads the ticker.txt off-screen. Below command shows a ticker loop starting off-screen. I would like to reload the text file only when the text is off-screen.
However reload does not accept expressions like `reload=eq(mod(150*t\,tw+w),0)`.

```
ffmpeg -i Background.mp4 -vf "drawtext=textfile=ticker.txt:fontfile=Effra_Std_Md.ttf: y=15:x=w-mod(150*t\,tw+w):reload=1" BackgroundAndTicker.mp4
```

Is there any other way to achieve an off-screen reload?

Comment: How often do you modify the textfile?

Comment: The ticker is a collection of news headlines. So 20 to 30 items a day is no exception, most of them during daytime. Only the newest 12 headlines are shown. If a new one comes in the oldest one is dropped from the collection.